# Find the swap options currently in use

Tags: linux, swap

If I mount my swap device as:

```
swapon --discard=once --discard=pages /dev/sdb
```

How do I later on check/find the options that I used, ie, `discard` in this example?

`swapon -s` only gives me:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sdb                partition   4194300 0       -1
```

`mount | grep swap` is null.

Comment: Does the syslog record the options?

Comment: @KenSharp Not in `dmesg`. Anywhere else I could look?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. I can't find anything that explains explicitly the swapon option mapping to the kernel swap data.

However, you can see almost all of the available swap options with this command (I believe this is correct, if not, let me know):

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt has documentation as of kernel 2.6 for the various files in this directory.

```
tail -n +1 /proc/sys/vm/*
==> /proc/sys/vm/admin_reserve_kbytes <==
8192

==> /proc/sys/vm/block_dump <==
0
tail: cannot open '/proc/sys/vm/compact_memory' for reading: Permission denied

==> /proc/sys/vm/compact_unevictable_allowed <==
1

==> /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio <==
20

==> /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs <==
3000

==> /proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio <==
50

==> /proc/sys/vm/dirtytime_expire_seconds <==
43200

==> /proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs <==
500

==> /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/extfrag_threshold <==
500

==> /proc/sys/vm/highmem_is_dirtyable <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/hugepages_treat_as_movable <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/hugetlb_shm_group <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/legacy_va_layout <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/lowmem_reserve_ratio <==
256 32  32

==> /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count <==
65530

==> /proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes <==
3466

==> /proc/sys/vm/min_slab_ratio <==
5

==> /proc/sys/vm/min_unmapped_ratio <==
1

==> /proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr <==
65536
tail: cannot open '/proc/sys/vm/mmap_rnd_bits' for reading: Permission denied

==> /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages_mempolicy <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/nr_overcommit_hugepages <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/nr_pdflush_threads <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/numa_zonelist_order <==
default

==> /proc/sys/vm/oom_dump_tasks <==
1

==> /proc/sys/vm/oom_kill_allocating_task <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_kbytes <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio <==
50

==> /proc/sys/vm/page-cluster <==
3

==> /proc/sys/vm/panic_on_oom <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/percpu_pagelist_fraction <==
0

==> /proc/sys/vm/stat_interval <==
1
tail: cannot open '/proc/sys/vm/stat_refresh' for reading: Permission denied

==> /proc/sys/vm/swappiness <==
60

==> /proc/sys/vm/user_reserve_kbytes <==
131072

==> /proc/sys/vm/vdso_enabled <==
1

==> /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure <==
100

==> /proc/sys/vm/watermark_scale_factor <==
10

==> /proc/sys/vm/zone_reclaim_mode <==
0
```

As you can see, if run with user permissions, a few options show error because they require root, if you run the command as root you'd get all the data.

Then it's a matter of researching to find out which swapon option maps to which /proc/sys/vm/ option.

I might use this method to get more data on swap as well for an application that collects such info.

The swapon man page is surprisingly vague when it comes to what its options actually do internally, so there's a missing piece here in terms of mapping one set of options to another set of values. Basically to fully answer this, one would have to learn what the swapon options actually *mean* internally in the kernel, at which point it becomes fairly obvious how to translate one type of data to another.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info, but back to the question... I can't see any filenames here related to `discard`, nor anything in your `vm.txt` link either.

Comment: As I said, the question remains of how the swapon options are mapped to the values listed. Or if there are other places that contain more data. The redhat readme lists what each file contains, as well. I doubt this is an easy answer to get without working at it a bit more. I know every time I have to figure out how to get meaningful user friendly output from /sys or /proc, it takes a bit of research, testing, etc, before I understand it. I'm interested in this because I may add it to a tool I do, if I can figure out any end user practical output.